# How to display images to html file using jquery? (some php and xml)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I have a folder with images called " LaptopsImages ".

In my file called laptops.php i have an array list with different laptops with variables like: title, brand, price, description, spec and pictures names. My  array list is convert to XML DOM tree.

On my file called product.html i wrote a code that take every product data  into the variables and display it:

```
var title = $theProduct.find('title').text();
var brand = $theProduct.find('brand').text();
var price = $theProduct.find('price').text();
var description = $theProduct.find('description').text();
var spec = $theProduct.find('spec');
var imageFilename = $theProduct.find('picture').text();

document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=title
document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML=brand
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML=price                        
document.getElementById("description").innerHTML=description
document.getElementById("spec").innerHTML=description
```

I have accomplished to display every product data into my html except the pictures for each laptop. Is any way that i can display pictures with the name they have already from my variable? Assume that the pictures have names " 0001.jpg , 0002.jpg " and so on.

Every picture can be taken from: var imageFilename=$theProduct.find('picture').text();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("picture").src = imageFilename
```

if there's a `<img>` tag with the id `picture`

Comment: I have done this and i have one more problem now. My local server is trying to find the pictures but they are in a sub folder.  Is any way that i can specify the way to look throw this folder?  The folder is called    "LaptopsImages".  Also when i check from console i saw this: GET http://localhost:8080/0001.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That's a problem with the method you're using to serve the images, and not the HTML or CSS or JS

Comment: No worries. I just found the solution. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery you can do :

```
$("#picture").attr("src", imageFilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myImage').src = imageFileName;
```

If you need the name from the ImageFileName then you can use:

```
name= imageFileName.substring(0, imageFileName.length - 4);/*to chop off .JPG*/
```

With Jquery:

```
$("#myImage").attr("src", imageFilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML= "<img src=\"" + imageurl+ "\">";
```

You can use this code to display a complete image in inner div where div id is price